# XACML3 Policy with multiple actions,subjects and resources

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, xacml2

Can i have the sample XACML3 Policy which has multi attributes such as actions,subjects and resources?

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you search through the internal, you could find many XACML 3.0 sample policies. XACML 3.0 core specification also contains sample policies. However, you can find lot of XACML 3.0 sample from [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/) blog. Also there are free tools and servers that help you to create XACML 3.0 policies. Such as [WSO2 Identity Server](http://xacmlinfo.org/tag/policy-editor/), [ALFA Plugin](https://www.axiomatics.com/axiomatics-alfa-plugin-for-eclipse.html) by Axiomatics  and so on.

Let me publish a simple policy that has been created from WSO2 Identity Server UI. This policy has been written for  "foo1" or "foo2" resources. And it says,  users "bob1" or "bob2"  can  perform "read" or "write" actions on this "foo1" or "foo2" resources. Other all access to "foo1" or "foo2" resources have been denied.

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="TestPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo1</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">foo2</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bob1</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">bob2</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule"/>
</Policy>
```